# Keeping string in JSONObject as string in containing JSONObject

Tags: java, json, groovy

Currently I have something like this:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
String thing = "[231,232,234]"
jsonObject.put("mything",thing)
JSONObject params = new JSONObject()
params.put("props",jsonObject)
```

The problem is when I look at `mything` in jsonObject it is a `String` which is correct.  However, when I look at `mything` in `params` it is a `JSONArray`.  How can I keep it a string?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with Groovy, its native `JsonBuilder` seems to work as expected:

```
import groovy.json.*

a = new JsonBuilder(mything: "[1, 2, 3]")

assert a.toString() == '{"mything":"[1, 2, 3]"}'

b = new JsonBuilder(params: a.getContent())

assert b.toString() == '{"params":{"mything":"[1, 2, 3]"}}'
```

Comment: it works, but when I look at net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject = a.getContent() it just converts that entry to a JsonArray

Comment: You need to use a JSONObject?

Comment: No but would like to use some sort of Json

Comment: Just use JsonBuilder, then. What else do you need to do with the Json object?

Answer (score -1):

What about calling toString() on the array to get a string representation out of it?