# JsonObject is converting String to JsonArray

Tags: java, json, groovy

Why is this changing the test element to a JSONArray and how do I stop it?

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray
import net.sf.json.JSONObject
HashMap<String,Object> stuff = new HashMap<String,Object>()
stuff.put("name","alex")
stuff.put("age","21")
stuff.put("consent",true)
stuff.put("test",'[1,2,true]')
JsonBuilder a = new JsonBuilder(stuff)
JSONObject b = a.getContent()
```

However, when I look at b the test property is a JsonArray.  How can I force it to keep it a String?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping string in JSONObject as string in containing JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761851/keeping-string-in-jsonobject-as-string-in-containing-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0):

Google tells me this is a pretty common problem with Groovy's `JsonBuilder`. If you can't change your data structures I'd suggest using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) instead, it gives you much better control over how your data is serialized and deserialized.

If you can change your data structures, I would suggest bundling all that stuff you're sticking in the `Map` in to a domain object. That way `JsonBuilder` will have data types to give it hints. I'm not 100% sure `JsonBuilder` will do the right thing, but it's more likely that it will if it doesn't have to guess at the data types.

If you had something like this simplified example

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean consent;
    String test;

    public Person(String name, int age, boolean consent, String test) {
        ...
    }                   
}

Person person = new Person("alex", 21, true, "[1,2,true]");

JsonBuilder a = new JsonBuilder(person);
JSONObject b = a.getContent();
```

you might have better luck.

Comment: tried this example didn't work.  Can't map Person to jsonObject

Comment: Use Gson instead then, if it doesn't do the right thing by default you can write your own deserializer for it.